# Powershell : Display the table headers once at the top in a html report

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to create an email report to display a list of failed/succeeded backup jobs.

Here is my script:

```
$servers = @(gc config\dbs.txt)
foreach($server in $servers)
{
  $dt = new-object "System.Data.DataTable"
  $cn = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection "server=$server;database=msdb;Integrated Security=sspi"
  $cn.Open()
  $sql = $cn.CreateCommand()
  $sql.CommandText = $(get-content config\query.sql)
  $rdr = $sql.ExecuteReader()
  $dt.Load($rdr)
  $cn.Close()
  $dt |ft Server,RunStatus,JobName >> $log
  $dt | ConvertTo-Html Server,JobName,RunStatus -head $a | ac logs\backups\report.htm    
}

Server      JobName     RunStatus
srv1        job1        success
srv1        job2        success
Server      JobName     RunStatus
srv2        job1        fail
srv2        job2        success
srv2        job3        success
Server      JobName     RunStatus
srv3        job1        fail
srv3        job2        success
srv3        job3        success
Server      JobName     RunStatus
srv4        job1        fail
srv4        job2        success
srv4        job3        success
Server      JobName     RunStatus
srv5        job1        fail
```

I am getting the header names multiple times as the content to the html file is being added after every foreach enumeration. Can I change my script so that the header [Server JobName RunStatus] is only displayed once at the top?

Also I want to know if it is possible to display the report.htm as inline content in the mail rather than an attachment. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.
steeluser

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Table headers are displayed for each enumeration because you are using `ConvertTo-HTML` in each enumeration :). The same applies to `format-table`. Try this out:

```
$dts = @()

@(gc config\dbs.txt) | % {
  $dt = new-object "System.Data.DataTable"
  $cn = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection "server=$server;database=msdb;Integrated Security=sspi"
  $cn.Open()
  $sql = $cn.CreateCommand()
  $sql.CommandText = $(get-content config\query.sql)
  $rdr = $sql.ExecuteReader()
  $dt.Load($rdr)
  $cn.Close()
  $dts += $dt
}

$dts |ft Server,RunStatus,JobName >> $log
$dts | ConvertTo-Html Server,JobName,RunStatus -head $a | ac logs\backups\report.htm
```

Comment: Thanks empo!!
This has worked.. I tried the  $dts += $dt thing earlier, but it failed because I was still doing the ConvertToHtml in the loop itself.. so i was getting only the last resultset from the $dt and it did NOT occur to me what I was doing wrong.. i guess long hours of work do that to you.. Cheers :-)

Comment: answer to my second question looks too complicated for me.. guess i need to take some time off for getting through it.. thanks for giving me a starting point.. :-) Have a great day.

Comment: In the second answer you have just a link to a function. You can download the function, dot-sourcing the related .ps1 in your script and then invoke the function as you would do with any other cmdlet :)